# Adding data to Jquery Ajax data object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to add more data to my data object before passed in ajax call.  I know push won't work because it is not an array.  What would the alternative to push be for an object?

```
var data = { 
    street: $('#FullStreetAddress').val(), 
    city: $('#City').val(), 
    state: $('#State').val(),
    doc_name: []
};

data.push({
    agent_id: agentID,
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.agent_id = agentID;
```

As you mentioned, `push` only works on an Array instance.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the property style syntax:

```
data.agent_id = agentID;
```

Using brackets is slightly more robust:

```
data['agent_id'] = agentID;
```

This is because any string can be used as a key in an object, but not as a property name. Eg:

```
data['agent.id'] = agentID; // works
data.agent.id = agentID; // error
```